# How to assign site roles for user group programatically in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am able to assign the site roles for user programatically by following API call,

```
UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserGroupRoles(userIds, mySite, SiteroleIds);
```

In the similar fashion can any one tell me that how can I assign the site roles for UserGroup programatically?

I have both usergroupID and SiteRoleId in my method so what API method should I need to call to assign the site roles for the user group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `addUserGroupGroupRoles(long userGroupId, long groupId, long[] roleIds)` of `UserGroupGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil` to assign SiteRoleId to userGroup. But you will need groupId as well.

Sample Code:

```
UserGroup userGroup = UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroup(userGroupId);
Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, "role name");
long[] roles = new long[] {role.getRoleId()};

UserGroupGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserGroupGroupRoles(userGroup.getUserGroupId(), 
    site.getGroupId(), roles);
```

Comment: Yes, group basically refers to site in Liferay.