# Add role to User in Liferay programmatically

Tags: java, authentication, liferay, user-roles

I need to assign roles to my Liferay's users when they log in the application.

I have implemented all the logic in the *'authenticateByScreenName'* method of a custom class that implements *'Authenticator'*.

Example code:

```
public class ESBAuthenticator implements Authenticator{

      public int authenticateByScreenName(long companyId, String screenName, String password,
            Map<String, String[]> headerMap, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap)

              setProfile(companyId, screenname);
              return 1;
     }

     public static void setProfile(long companyId, long userId){
           User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);
           Role liferayRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.fetchRole(companyId, "Administrator");
           RoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserRole(user.getUserId(), liferayRole.getRoleId());
           UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(user);
     }
 }
```

When I log-in, apparently it works, I check liferay database's tables and they are updated, my user has "Administrator" role assigned. However, the portal in front-end doesn't show the "Admin" option.

[image]

But If I go to 'My Account', press the 'save' button, log-out and log-in again I have the Admin options availables.

Anyone know why this happens?, I am calling 'updateUser()' after assign the role, It is not the same as the 'save' button?

**Possible solution:**
I have found that If I clear the content cached across the cluster it works fine. I found it in this post:

https://www.liferay.com/es/web/kamesh.sampath1/blog/-/blogs/how-to-clear-liferay-cache

Add the following line:

```
MultiVMPoolUtil.clear();
```

Anyone know if is this the right solution?, I can't find what does liferay when the "save" button from the "my_account" page is pressed. Maybe it clear this cache?. I was searching for a synchronize with database function but couldn't find anything. It seems to be that if a column is updated, liferay doesn't use it if it's cached :(.

Comment: Is it pre-authenticator or post-authenticator? I believe if its post-authenticator then user-context wont get updated with admin privileges.

Comment: It is pre-authenticator :S.

Comment: Try `UserLocalServiceUtil.addRoleUser(long roleId, long userId)` instead!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557938/how-can-i-assign-a-role-to-a-user-in-liferay/32559009#32559009

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a cheap hack.

Step 1: Make sure you have the hold of user credential.

Step 2: Do as necessary to change user roles etc

Step 3: Flush all kinds of cache (client or server) related to the flow

Step 4: redirect the user to a temp view where the user credential you held will be applied automatically and then redirected to the portal.

Lemme know whether it works

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not work on this project anymore :(.

Comment: Oh! I missed to see the posted date.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method you are passing screenName

```
 setProfile(companyId, screenname);
```

But in ur setProfileMethod, you are using UserId

```
 public static void setProfile(long companyId, long userId){
           User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);
           Role liferayRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.fetchRole(companyId, "Administrator");
           RoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserRole(user.getUserId(), liferayRole.getRoleId());
           UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(user);
     }
```

Use Method

```
UserLocalServiceUtil.fetchUserByScreenName(companyId, screenName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution of clear cache works because you need to remove all cached portlets repsones. This is the way my_account do it.

```
 // Clear cached portlet responses
 PortletSession portletSession = actionRequest.getPortletSession();
 InvokerPortletImpl.clearResponses(portletSession);
```

The problem is that InvokerPortletImpl is not visible externally. to replicate this functionally you can try a  *login.events.post*  and get the responses cache from the HttpSession e clear the map;

```
  httprequest.getSession().getAttribute("CACHE_PORTLET_RESPONSES").clear()
```

but it is like a hack its better in this case MultiVMPoolUtil.clear();